# Any function to Download rendered images from Fetched Api in javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried to get random images from unsplash api by given code below, now i am looking for to way to DOWNLOAD displayed image from that Api

```
const numItemsToGenerate = 1; 
function renderItem(){
      fetch(`https://source.unsplash.com/920x720? 
            beach`).then((response)=> {   
           let item = document.getElementById('container');
            item.innerHTML = `
            <img class="beach_image" src="${response.url}" 
        alt="beach image"/>
                            `   
          })   
          }
    for(let i=0;i<numItemsToGenerate;i++){
   renderItem();
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a function, that downloads the image from the unsplash. But the problem is, it doesn't work on Stackoverflow's snippet, since is creates `null` blob URL. You need to run this program on a server (like `localhost`), in order to work.

Try it on - https://jsfiddle.net/xt5wb2vn/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
</div>
<button class="download">Click to download</button>
```

JavaScript

```
const numItemsToGenerate = 1;

function downloadImage(url) {
  let a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = url;
  a.download = 'image.jpg';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);

}

 function renderItem() {
   fetch(`https://source.unsplash.com/920x720?beach`)
  .then(resp => resp.blob())
  .then(image => {
    const image_url = URL.createObjectURL(image)
    let item = document.getElementById('container');
    item.innerHTML = `<img class="beach_image" src="${image_url}" alt="beach image"/>`;
    return image_url;
  }).then(url=>document.querySelector(".download").onclick = ()=>downloadImage(url))
}

renderItem()
```

Comment: its Downloading the image everytime i refresh the page, if there any option to Download it via Button Onclick??? TIA

Comment: @Sdev I have updated my Answer above. Please Check.

Answer (score 1):

Use `URL.createObjectURL`

So, the function should look like

```js
fetch(`https://source.unsplash.com/920x720?beach`)
  .then(resp => resp.blob())
  .then(image => {
    const image_url = URL.createObjectURL(image)
    const item = document.getElementById('container')
    item.src = image_url
  })
```

Comment: Its downloading another random image from api, not the one displayed,

Comment: You're using unsplash's random search api.